# Nested models with mutate and formula

Tags: r, dplyr, glm

I am trying to run multiple models on nested datafraames. The formula is running as null and the models don't seem to be working. When I test it individually it works fine. Any thoughts?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(MASS)
df<-mtcars 
getmodelaic <- function(df) {
  mdl <- glm.nb(mpg ~ cyl +hp +drat+wt+qsec+gear+am +carb , data = df)
  mdl <- stepAIC(mdl, trace = FALSE)
return (mdl)}

nested<- mtcars %>%  group_by(vs, disp) %>% nest()
nested_models <- nested  %>% 
  mutate (model = map(data, getmodelaic), formula = map(model, formula))
```

Comment: If I copy/paste your example, it fails even individually because there are not enough observations to converge: `glm.nb(mpg ~ cyl +hp +drat+wt+qsec+gear+am +carb , data = nested$data[[1]])`. If I nest only by `vs` (and not `disp`) to have enough observations, your code works fine (well with lots of warnings but that's due to the data).

Comment: Thanks. The Formula mutation returns nulls in another bit of code with data I can't share. Is it possible that I am having some interactions between libraries? How can I make sure the right function is used?

Comment: By indicating the name of the package `stats::formula`. But if you just execute on one of the nested subdataframes, then run `formula(mdl)`, do you still get a problem?

Comment: No. That is the weird part. The mutate is run on existing column on that name, but from my understanding transmute is not used any more so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: This also does not seem to work. `nested_nb$formula <- formula(nested_nb$model)`

Comment: This is the error message. `Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `formula`.
x Can't convert NULL to function
i Input `formula` is `map(model, formula)`.
i The error occurred in row 1.
Backtrace:`

Comment: If you remove the `formula=` part and only run the `mutate(model=` part, then manually inspect the models with `nested_models$model[[1]]`, does it look fine? Do all the models in that column look fine? If just 1 failed to compute you may get a NULL. Try also changing the name of the column from formula to something else, if the data frame is actually masking the `formula()` function (that would explain the error message `Can't convert NULL to function`). And try replacing with `stats::formula()`.